# Alternative to Google Adsense which has good international coverage

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, revenue, money

I have a technical blog (programming related) which has around 500 visit per days, 70% are international visitors and 30% are from US/CA.

Google Adsense disabled my account due to invalid clicks so I can't use them (no need to explain here, they suck hard and never respect and listen to the publishers' appeal)

I have tried adbrite and recently using chitika but they almost give me nothing, e.g.

**chitika**

13,865 Page Views
4 clicks
$0.01

The performance is so poor even I don't want to mention about it. I am already putting a full top banner and a 350x200 box in article body.

I am researching if any alternative would provide more revenue for my internation visitors or technical visitors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same happened to me, my research took me to [BuySellAds](https://buysellads.com/), I've seen great sites that use their system,  take a look at the ads of [Iconfinder](http://www.iconfinder.com).

**The Good**: BuySellAds is slightly different than adsense, I like it because the advertiser buys a spot on your site; they also support CPM based ads, etc.
**The Bad**: they take a big cut IMAO.

Also I think you should try to implement your own adbased solution or try an ad service provider such as http://www.adzerk.com/ (StackOverflow uses it).

Good luck with your research.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Adbrite, they are equally good as Google adsense.

Answer (score 0):

i would look at

http://media.net/

buysellads.com - slightly different as people will target your site on its content

http://www.interclick.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Clicksor - It's one of the most popular advertisement networks**

and a good alternative to Google Adsense which is available for free on the internet. They allow you to earn through different ad-formatslike In-line Text Ads, Contextual Ads (banner and text) and more. You can earn up to 60% of the revenue share, depending on the performance the advertisers attain from your website placements and clicks.